# .ASPXAUTH Cookie Not HttpOnly

Tags: asp.net, httponly, .aspxauth

A security scanner was run against an ASP.NET application, and flagged the `.ASPXAUTH` cookie because it is not `HttpOnly`.  How do I force this to be `HttpOnly`?

Comment: How are you creating your auth cookie? FormsAuthenticationTicket? `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`?

Comment: I suppose I don't know.  But I just did a search and I do see `FormsAuthenticationTicket` in this code, so I suppose that's what's used.

Comment: Have you tried to set the HttpOnly flag to true in the Web.config?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228262%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @Adrian: Yes, actually, and this did nothing

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET 1.x app?

Comment: @vcsjones: This was once a .NET 1.x app, long ago, but has since been converted to .NET 3.5